# Обработать неизвестное количество строк в Python

Tags: python

Как на Питоне обрабатывать последовательный ввод строк, если

1. не указано количество этих самых строк. То есть нельзя применить цикл **for**,
2. кроме того, не сказано чем ввод будет закончен, то есть нельзя применить цикл **while**?

Comment: Откуда взялось ограничения 1? `for` в Python легко справляется с неизвестным количеством строк, например при чтении из файла.

Comment: Ограничение 1 взялось из задач следующего типа: на ввод подается некое  кол-во строк, причем не в файле.  Нужно их обработать и что-то сделать. Вот пример такой задачи- http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/dicts/problems/sales/

Comment: Например так: http://ideone.com/Zwznnu
Понятно, что можно было просто циклом while сделать, но часто проще сначала распарсить входные данные, а потом циклом for по ним пройтись. Цикл for работает с любым итерируемым объектом, не обязательно определённой длины.

Answer (score 5):

Файл в питоне можно итерировать по строкам, например,

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # делаем что угодно со строкой, например
    print(len(line))
```

Такое будет работать, только если стандарнтый поток ввода не подключен к терминалу, а например, происходит перенаправление из регулярного файла.

---

Либо можно читать файл по одной строке.

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if line == '':
        break
    # обработка
    print(len(line))
```

Разумеется, совсем без циклов обойтись не получится.

Чтобы во всех этих случаях остановиться, когда ввод происходит с терминала, надо нажать <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (в Linux) или <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> (в Windows).

Comment: Цикл while здесь ни к чему: это просто многословный способ первый for-цикл написать (если баг с read-ahead буфером на Питоне 2 не рассматривать).

Answer (score 2):

Вводим ограничение, что чтение идет только через `input`. Eсли данные завершились, бросается исключение `ValueError` (как в PythonTutor) или `EOFError` (как в Ideone).

### Через `while`

```
while True:
    try:
        try:
            line = input()
        except (ValueError, EOFError):
            break
        # здесь можно как-то строку обработать
        print(line)
```

### Через `for`

"Упаковываем" цикл while в функцию, и превращаем в итератор (плюс деление каждой строки по пробельным символам):

```
def inputs():
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
            # Здесь может происходить какая-то предварительная обработка данных:
            data = line.split()
            yield data
        except (ValueError, EOFError):
            return

for name, purchase, count in inputs():
    # Окончательная обработка данных
    print(name, purchase, count)
```

Часто бывает удобно делать именно вторым вариантом, если первоначальная обработка (парсинг) текста довольно сложна, и нужно отделить её от собственно обработки данных.

Comment: Можно ввод/вывод и вычисления разделять: `for line in iter_except(input, (ValueError, EOFError)): words = line.split()...` где `iter_except()` это [itertools  рецепт](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). Можно просто [`more_itertools` модуль поставить](http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.iter_except)